# What does the expression "as bad as it is" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does the expression "as bad as it is" mean? Does it mean **on top of that** for e.g. as bad something (accident or something like that) is, something similarly bad?

> I have been sick all week. As bad as it is, there are exams this weekend.

Or is it similar to "even though", like this expression:

> As much as I like you, I don't agree with you on this.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples it could be replaced by *in spite of* or *despite*.

> In spite of the fact that I've been sick all week, there are exams this weekend [that I have to get through].
>
> Despite how much I like you, I don't agree with you on this.

That should make the meaning clearer.

Comment: As your *[that I have to get through]* implies, I don't think OP's first example represents a particularly credible utterance. The *[as] xxx as it is* construction pretty much requires a "contrasting" conjunction, and for *"I'm sick"*, I don't think *"[but/and] there are exams this weekend"* contrasts as clearly as *"**I have to sit** those exams"*. OP's version would do better with something like *"On top of all that"*, or *"And if that weren't bad enough"*. Which isn't how the construction would be paraphrased in his example #2.

Comment: @Robusto Thabks for the answer, I understand the use of despite / in spite, but I want to know what does as bas as it is mean?

Comment: It's meaning is literal: *Even given how bad it [the situation] is* something still must be done that would have been easier if [the situation] were not the case.

Answer (score 1):

"As bad as it is" implies that while you think the situation is bad, it could be worse. At that point you either supply a reason that the situation is actually worse:

> As bad as the report is, he now wants to add 5 pages about lint traps.

... or you provide a contrast to show it isn't as bad as it could be:

> As bad as the movie is, at least they don't literally jump a shark.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong. It's common parlance now, and has been for 20 or 30 years; but it's still wrong.

These days we say
As bad as it is, it could be a whole lot worse
when we SHOULD say
Bad as it is, it could be a whole lot worse.

We should still say
I may be bad, but I'm not as bad as he is.

It may be too late to correct it now, but that doesn't mean it's right; and if you want to avoid being thought illiterate, do it as above.

(I'm old - 84 - but don't fall into the trap of thinking 'as bad as it is' is a new fashion in speech: it is, and always will be, simply wrong.)

Comment: You don't actually explain why it's wrong.